# subcategory images in category page in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am not able to see any changes after editing opencart 2.0.3.1, I am not getting the images and also edited the files from category.php (catlog>controller>product) and category.tpl(catlog>view>theme>*>template>product) and replaced

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
```

and

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
```

with

```
if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image-        >resize($result['image'], 100, 100);
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image-        >resize('placeholder.png', 100, 100);
            }

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config-    >get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product-    >getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path='     . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url),
                'thumb' => $image
            );
```

and

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div>
    <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo     $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo     $category['name']; ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

respectively but not able to get any thing! Help highly appreciated

Comment: Did you check the error logs ? Also check the file/folder permissions.

Comment: Did you `print_r($data['categories']);` ?

Comment: On checking the errorlog it says 500, the server error! And print_r($data['categories']); also not working